# How to enable ctags for PRO*C files.?

Tags: c, ctags, cscope

When i generate ctags, tags are generated only for C files.
It is not populating tags for proc*c (.pc) files.

Comment: What have you tried already? In which context do you use it? What is the command line?

Answer (score 0):

ctags --language-force=C++ *.pc